# Python Pandas: Aggregate rows conditional value picking

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-3.5

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dim': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'A', 3: 'B', 4: 'A'},
                   'id': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 3},
                   'value1': {0: nan, 1: 1.2, 2: 2.0, 3: nan, 4: 3.0},
                   'value2': {0: 1.0, 1: 2.0, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan}})

  dim  id  value1  value2
0   A   1     NaN     1.0
1   B   1     1.2     2.0
2   A   2     2.0     NaN
3   B   2     NaN     NaN
4   A   3     3.0     NaN
```

I now want to aggregate the values for different dimensions over the id, so that the following is true:
If dim == 'A' is not None then take the value from dim == 'A' else take value where dim == 'B' (if it is not None). If both are None, just take None.

So the result should be:

```
   id  value1  value2
0   1     1.2     1.0
1   2     2.0     NaN
2   3     3.0     NaN
```

My guess is, I would need to use some form of group by function, but I am not too sure. Maybe something with apply?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and [`swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) for reshape and then [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index(['id','dim']).unstack().swaplevel(0,1,axis=1)
#alternative
#df1 = df.pivot('id','dim').swaplevel(0,1,axis=1)
print (df1)
dim      A      B      A      B
    value1 value1 value2 value2
id                             
1      NaN    1.2    1.0    2.0
2      2.0    NaN    NaN    NaN
3      3.0    NaN    NaN    NaN

df2 = df1['A'].combine_first(df1['B']).reset_index()
print (df2)
   id  value1  value2
0   1     1.2     1.0
1   2     2.0     NaN
2   3     3.0     NaN
```

Similar solution with [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) for select `MultiIndex`:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['id','dim']).unstack()
#alternative
#df1 = df.pivot('id','dim')
print (df1)
    value1      value2     
dim      A    B      A    B
id                         
1      NaN  1.2    1.0  2.0
2      2.0  NaN    NaN  NaN
3      3.0  NaN    NaN  NaN

df2 = df1.xs('A', axis=1, level=1).combine_first(df1.xs('B', axis=1, level=1)).reset_index()
print (df2)
   id  value1  value2
0   1     1.2     1.0
1   2     2.0     NaN
2   3     3.0     NaN
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much - it works :-)
For anyone that has multiple columns to combine, just use multiple calls of combine after each other.